# Add Colon After Each Element in a List

Tags: python

I have the following text file:

```
4 #Highest Number
1 2
2 3
3 4
1 4
```

I'm trying to create a row for each number in the range from 1 to my highest number. 
That is, something when printed out would look like this:

```
1:
2:
3:
4:
```

I tried creating two sets, one of integers from 1 to 4 and another of 4 :'s and using a union to combine them together but my set of :'s looked like this:

```
{':'}
```

Rather than this:

```
{:,:,:,:}
```

Here's my code as it is right now.

```
Input_File = input("Enter your file: ").lower()
with open(Input_File, 'r') as f:
   first_line = f.readline()
   data = f.read().splitlines()


number_of_pairs = int(first_line) + 1
colons_needed = int(first_line) * [':']
colons_needed = set(colons_needed)
headers = list(range(1, number_of_pairs))
headers = set(headers)
```

Update:

This is what I'm getting so far:

```
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
4: 5
```

I would like:

```
1:
2:
3:
4:
```

The code used to get this is:

```
for i in range(1, len(my_list)):
    print(str(i)+':', my_list[i])
```

When I try to add a +1 to the end of my_list I receive an out of range error

I got it to work, thank you for the help!

Comment: "It didn't work" is not an adequate problem description. Don't be discouraged! You've at least *posted an attempt*. But in any event, the union of two sets is probably not what you want.

Comment: A set will never look like this `{':',':',':'}` because sets only contain unique values. So, if you write `{':',':',':'}` you'll notice it evalutates to `{':'}` In other words, `{':',':',':'} == {':'}`

Comment: Oh, I seem to have forgotten that sets only held unique values. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, but I think you should just change your approach. Consider @Prune answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you simply handle this as part of the output formatting.  Don't maintain the colons *at all* in your program, just add them when you print, something like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(my_list)+1):
    print str(i)+':', my_list[i]
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting an invalid syntax error when I try to implement this. Perhaps, I'm doing it wrong

Comment: 'code' for i in range(1, len(headers)+1):
    print str(i)+':', headers[i] 'code'

Comment: @RGPython A syntax error when you try `print item` ??? are you sure you're using Python 2,x

Comment: Glad it worked.  My area still has a lot of Python 2.7